# Function to execute batch file C++

Tags: c++, batch-file, cmd

I want to execute a batch file using system() and the path to the file will be passed to the function so it will look like this:

```
void executeBatch(char* BatchFile){
    system(BatchFile);
}
```

Now the issue is that the path passed in will not have the escape quotes to ignore spaces for example the user would input:

```
"C:\\Users\\500543\\Documents\\Batch File Project\\Testing.bat"
```

How do I add escape quotes to the path passed in?

So I essentually change:

```
"C:\\Users\\500543\\Documents\\Batch File Project\\Testing.bat"
```

to

```
"\"C:\\Users\\500543\\Documents\\Batch File Project\\Testing.bat\""
```

Comment: Don't take a non-const `char *` if you don't plan on changing it.

Comment: And just use `std::string` to make it quick and painless, though I suggest using an API that's designed to open a file, not execute arbitrary commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want something like that:

```
void executeBatch(char* BatchFile){
string cmd(BatchFile)
string expandCmd = string("\"") + cmd + string("\"");
system(expandCmd.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Yes but this doesn't work. For one it is underlining the `""\" + cmd + "\"";` and says \ is an unrecognized token. Also it underlines `expandCmd` and says it is not suitable because it is not a `const char*`

Comment: I agree, sorry I'm not in front of a computer. edited my answer! hope it should work, there is so many way to append string.

Comment: Oh figured it out I just changed the first problem to `expandCmd = '\"' + cmd + '\"';`